# swagger POST with form-post body and json

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

How can I document following curl request on Swagger?

Also, I want to document the JSON structure in POST fields (`payload` in following example), is it possible with Swagger?

```
curl \
-d "type: type1" \
-d "token: 54596977" \
-d "payload: {\"summary\":\"quick summary\",\"color\":\"#e76ce6\",\"role\":\"owner\"}" \
http://localhost/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 1):

That curl doesn't make much sense.  If you are passing formData for `type` and `token`, then your payload as a JSON body should really not be sent in a http FORM post.  Consider either passing type and token as query params and header params respectively, and the payload as a proper JSON body POST.  That will make the most sense to the end users.

Comment: I am stuck with a legacy end point that needs to be documented.

Comment: Then set the payload to be type `string` and document it as accepting JSON